# Forever Node.JS Express 4

Tags: express, npm, forever, express-4

How do you run the Express 4 app with Forever? (or is there a new package?)

I am running my Express 3 apps with [Forever](https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever) installed locally with the package manager. I use the command:

```
forever -a start app.js
```

Comment: like magic I post to SO and find something on the next (one million and 1) search: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2. Is this legit?

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
forever start ./bin/www
```

Let's take a look to `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
},
```

I guess when we call `npm start`, `./bin/www` will be executed at some point.
Then look at the content of`./bin/www`:

```
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

so we are ready to listen for connections.

Answer (score 14):

```
forever start --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 ./bin/www
```

Comment: I've seen this answer all over, but no explanation as to how `./bin/www` could have any idea at all where your app.js file is, or what it's named.

Answer (score 2):

If you use npm start to run your app, this works in place of it:

```
forever start -c "npm start" /path/to/app/dir/
```

Source: https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/issues/540

Answer (score 1):

Try `node app.js` first, for me, I added a new module in code base, but i did not run `npm install` in my AWS box, forever is not giving you the error, it just stopped silently, but node will give you the error

Answer (score 0):

http://expressjs.com/guide.html

in Expressjs guide doc,

use 'npm start'

I want use 'forever' but can not too

so,

add code at 'app.js'

`var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});`

and

$node app.js

can use it.

and forever can use too

Comment: I see this got a down vote with no comment. That is not fair. If you think this is wrong say why. I am still using express 3. I tried pm2 but it didn't even 'hello world'.

Comment: hm... do you $node app.js ?
it doesn't start or occur error -> code check,
nothing on console -> please check debug or upload your code

Comment: @EricSheasby I think the reason this got down voted is because this doesn't answer the question at all. You are asking how to use forever to start a node application and pineoc explicitly says they don't know how in their answer but try to provide an answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Feb 2021

This solution is for express.js & forever, on Windows OS.

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "set PORT=3001 && set DEBUG=myapp:* && forever start --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 ./bin/www",
}
```

Now run:

```
npm start
```

NOTE: For other OS, and customization see following link: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html