# Start server node.js with forever on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, npm, forever

I been searching alot and no result with same problem as me. 
I have a Node.js application and I want to start it with `forever start app.js`, the process starts but no website found when i try in browser. The process is in the list when I write `forever list`.

`Npm start` works fine but I cant use nodejs/node app.js or my_file.js.. It gives no error or something just new command line with no output in terminal.

So anyone know why I cant start the app with `nodejs app.js` or `forever start app.js` .. No files works.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you run `node app.js`?

Comment: firstly, there is no commant like "nodejs app.js", only "node app.js". if it works - forever should work too.

Comment: @Jarema - Actually they changed the default command for node recently so if you didn't have it from an earlier version, it defaults to using `nodejs` as the name of the executable.. Rather annoying

Comment: omg. I use node in some production enviroments, but with frozen dependencies... good for me. look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072812/forever-node-js-express-4
if You're using any code generators  AND expressjs(i dont, so i dont know).

Comment: @TMan No I don't get any errors, I output nothing.

Comment: Elyas74 answer doesnt help?

Still - looking at package.json and "scripts" should help a lot. There is defined how app is starting.

Comment: is your app working at all? Could you post some code/a gist? It sounds like the problem isn't with forever but with your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In express 4 you should write :

```
forever ./bin/www
```

And if you check your `package.json` file you can see :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  }
```

It's the `npm start` script

Comment: It's working, but when I close terminal, server also shutdown

Comment: NVM, I just added forever start ./bin/www :)
Thanks alot!

Comment: Okey, will check that.

Comment: @CoderMe if u r using linux, try `pm2`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try using [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2).

It does a great job at keeping your app alive, and has some really useful features such as load balancing, no downtime, and a web interface to monitor your processes.

In addition, I find it dead simple to use.

Comment: I agree that pm2 is great... but for production.
It tends keep port in use even after application is stopped/deleted, and the only way to solve it is to use pm2 kill, which kills all apps.

Not a big deal, but it sometimes is frustrating in development. Especially if You have lot of apps on the same server. 

For production - its jsut great.

Comment: @Jarema totally agree with you, the port thing is very annoying in development