# Why does my node app process keep getting stopped when I use forever?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, forever

On a free-tier Amazon EC2 instance, I set up a simple node.js Hello World app running on express.

If I run `npm start`, my app runs fine and I can hit it from my browser, and I see the following output:

```
> myappname@0.0.0 start /home/ec2-user/app
> node ./bin/www
```

I have installed the forever tool globally. When I run `forever start app.js`, I see:

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: app/app.js
```

However, when I check `forever list`, I see that the process has stopped:

```
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command             script forever pid  id logfile                          uptime  
data:    [0] 2v0J /usr/local/bin/node app.js 2455    2457    /home/ec2-user/.forever/2v0J.log STOPPED
```

This is the only message in the log: `error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: null`

I'm unable to find any other log information. Why does it keep immediately stopping?

EDIT: I tried running it as `nohup forever start app.js` and got the same problem. I'm running the `forever start` and the `forever list` in the same ssh session, one after the other. The app's process seems to stop immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem thanks to this answer on a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24914916/1791634

The process kept running when I used `forever start ./bin/www` instead of passing app.js

It remains to be seen whether this causes any trouble down the road.

Comment: why should they even allow `forever ./bin/www` if the objective to use forever is achieved only if `forever start ./bin/www` is used

Comment: without the start , you can see the log on the SSH console

Comment: But why do I `forever myscript.js` if I can just `node myscript.js` without using forever?

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing the process stops after you disconnect from ssh?

Try running forever with `nohup` first.

```
nohup forever start app.js
```

When you disconnect from ssh the server kills all your shell's child processes.  `nohup` disconnects a process from its parent shell.

Comment: I'm running `forever start app.js` and `forever list` in the same ssh session, and it is always immediately stopped. I just tried running it as `nohup forever start app.js` and got the same result: the forever process was stopped as soon as I checked it.

Comment: Check the log file.  Is your node process dying from a script error?

Comment: If I check the logfile shown in `forever list`, all I see is the error listed in the above question. Is there another log file I can check?

Comment: I believe `&` it's missing on nohup command.. ie: `nohup forever start app.js &`

Comment: You have to invoke "forever start <your_script_file.js>". In your case (as seen when you do npm start) the file is located at ./bin/www , not at "app.js". Regards

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to use "sudo forever" for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting the server after updating the code. Pull the latest code and run

```
npm install
```

Now run

```
forever start app.js
```

This will fix the issue